# Calculating diagonal end coordinates in latitudes and longitudes, if midpoint coordinates and distance is known, using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, latitude-longitude

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I want the coordinates of top left end and bottom right end of a diagonal of a square, and I know the mid point of the line joining them and the length of side of the square should be 5km?

Can anyone help me with this calculation?

I want a region from map such that it is of area 5*5km and the center of the diagonal is known and I want to calculate the latitude and longitude values of both ends of the diagonal.

**To put it simple, i want the geographical coordinates of corner points of a square of side 5km, when the mid point coordinates of the square is known**

Comment: Take the top left and add 5km to X to get Top Right, subtract 5km from the X of lower right to get lower left.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ian, but the coordinates are geographical and they look something like this longitude,latitude=(-98.1216 49.7608). So can you please tell how can I subtract 5km from such data

Comment: You could convert your data to UTM coordinates and follow Ian's advice .  This would be the simplest approach.  Otherwise, search this website on information on using a haversine formula.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: what tool are you using? does it not handle reprojection?

Comment: I'm Using ARCGis Pro for creating shape files....BTW I don't know the top left coordinates